# Necesito sumar dos numeros de mas de 255 bits en assembler

Tags: ensamblador

se que es una pregunta muy basica, pero me estoy comiendo la cabeza intentando saber como se hace.

Estoy utilizando un Motorola 6800 con [este](http://www.hvrsoftware.com/6800emu.htm) emulador.

Tengo dos numeros, y su suma da mas de 255, se que tengo que usar ADC pero no se como guardar el resultado.

```
ldaa #255 ; Cargar primer numero(255) en el acumulador A
staa $00f0 ; Guardar A en la memoria $00f0
ldaa #30 ; Cargar segundo numero(30) en el acumulador A
adca $00f0 ; Añadir ambos numeros con carry
```

Aca me quedo con el carry flag en 1, y el numero 29 en el acumulador A (que hasta donde yo se, significa que el resultado es 255+accA+1).

Como guardo el resultado?

Comment: Lo coloco en comentario porque tengo la duda ya que me hiciste  desempolvar mis conocimientos de assembler y no sé si recuerde bien. Has buscado sobre el manejo de registros extendidos? o variables del tipo WORD o DWORD? Revisa esto dos links que pueden ser de ayuda [registros extendidos assembler](http://seguesec.blogspot.com/2011/01/principios-en-ensamblador.html), [PDF assembler longitud de variables](https://www.cs.buap.mx/~mgonzalez/asm_mododir2.pdf),

Answer (score 3):

Los números mayores a los acumuladores se pueden definir en memoria, con
 `adc` puedes sumar números de más de 8 bits. En este código no utilizo `adc`,
porque solo son ocho bits. No estoy seguro de si esas son las instrucciones son
precisas, pero detallo el principio en los comentarios.

```
ldaa #255  ; Cargar sumando 255 en [00f0]
staa $00f0
clr  #00f1 ; Vaciar [00f1] para guardar ahí el resultado sin acarreo
clr  #00f2 ; Vaciar [00f2] para guardar el acarreo
ldaa #30   ; Cargar sumador 30 en A
adda $00f0 ; Sumar A + [00f0] y guardarlo en A y carry queda en 1
staa $00f1 ; guardar la suma en [00f1]
bcc        ; branch si no hay nada en el carry
inc  $00f2 ; si hubo algo en el carry, colocar en 1 [00f2]
```

... y la memoria ya está guardando el resultado en memoria.

Answer (score 1):

el lenguaje ensamblador que conozco es ARM.

Pero conocimiento básico de Ensamblador y alto nivel incluso:
El resultado se guarda en 8 bits, por lo tanto no lo puedes guardar así fácilmente.

Lo que sí puedes hacer es intentar usar registros o variables con más longitud de bits para no perder esa precisión. Hasta donde yo sé, no puedes quedarte con el Carry, porque es un Flag temporal. Lo que quizá sí puedas hacer es tener cuidado de no machacar el Carry y leerlo para acabar de escribir las condiciones posteriores o valores posteriores que necesites.